# Panel data set with repeated values for dependent variables

Tags: panel-data

If dependent variable is an expost value for N entities for (say for year 2008 only) while values for explanatory variables are available for past several years, can we design a panel data by repeating our dependent variable over all ex-ante years?

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Table below further explains my question where we can see that dependent variable doesn't change across time, while two explanatory variables do change.

[image]

Thanks